# I have so much "not selected" index

Tags: google-index

[image]

This is a [screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FBw3.jpg) from web master tools. It shows I have a large number of "not selected" pages, first I thought if I fix duplicate content with 301 redirects and a sitemap, the problem will be solved, but it doesn't seem to be making any difference.

(On 9/16/12 I made sitemap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's explained in the tooltip next to "Not selected":

> URLs from your site that redirect to other pages or URLs whose contents are substantially similar to other pages.

If you had duplicate pages and you redirected them all to a canonical version, the "Not selected" number will not reduce because instead of a URL being ignored due to duplication, that same URL is now ignored because it redirects somewhere else.

In short, it should not be anything to worry about. You are doing the right thing by redirecting. [More information here.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2642366)

Comment: I had around 50K 'Not Selected' urls on Nov'2012, Since middle of the January I see the number is reduced to 2K. I did do nothing though. Is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

Try to look for useless pages, with thin content, duplicate content, useless content. As you do not provide any hint on your site, it's hard to give any other suggestion.

Comment: its a eCommerce site, so almost %80 product details, %10 categories and ect. so there is almost no useless page or thin content. there were some issiues about duplicate pages like https/http/www kind of problems. I redirected all pages to correct ones and used canonical urls.

Comment: Well, if you are sure all your product pages are unique, and you category pages have content, no you don't have thin/duplicate content. I don't know about 301 and canonical page regarding the WMT graphs, they may appear in the not-selected index.

Answer (score 0):

As they explain on [google webmaster tools](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139066), similar content may not necessairly be considered duplicated content, but also it may not be indexed. Using [cannonical URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139066) may help you.
This is not necessairly a bad thing, if pages with similar content have been indexed by google.