# can't find my site on google search

Tags: seo, google-search

I write "XXX" on google search with location and language filter and look for 50+ pages and can't see my site, then same filters and search like this "site:www.foo.com XXX" google finds 10+ pages. so how can I understand why my page doesn't come up in even first 50 pages?

I have all SEO stuff + more then 5 year domain registered.

thanks for your guideness

Comment: Have you looked into Google Webmaster Tools to see if there's any issues listed in there?

Comment: I dont see anyproblem on webmaster tools, also I asked a question about webmaster tools on here If you like to check http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35460/i-have-so-much-not-selected-index

Comment: If your site showed up with these keywords, you may be penalized by google. Do you have duplicate content on your site ?

Comment: I have some cloth products 3 sizes so ever size has different page but same content. but which I google is not a cloth product. I had some https/http and www.foo.com/foo.com problems I used 301 redirect to solve these duplicates. If I penalized how can I know that and how to clear my domain.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest checking Google Webmaster Tools for duplicate content issues. You'll specifically want to make sure that you're page titles are unique for each different page, and that the meta descriptions are unique as well.

If Google believes the pages to be duplicates, it will likely relegate them to their supplementary index, which is why you see them for site: searches, but not regular searches.

A good way to confirm if that's the case is to search for a very unique and long string that appears on a page you're investigating, and do a quoted Google search for it, something like ["at domain.com we strive to provide the highest quality product available online"], anything that's unlikely to show up on other pages on the internet. If you're page doesn't show up, chances are quite high that it's been relegated to the supplementary index. If that's the case, you'll want to fix up your duplicate content issues and submit a reconsideration request to Google (which can take several weeks).

Comment: I did search a long sentance google find 2 page results and my site only match and It was latest result at the end of second page :/ after that I found another sentance medium size google found 2 pages and my site was first one. last I tried 3 word which is possible to match with other sites google found 4 page results and my site was at the latest page.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like Google hasn't indexed any of your pages. In Webmaster tools you are able to view the number of pages of your site that Google has crawled and cached.

You may simply have a wrongly placed no-index tag or your robot.txt file has been set up incorrectly.

The first thing I'd do would be to submit a sitemap to Webmaster tools.

Comment: If it comes up with a "site:" query then they must be indexed.

Comment: From my understanding, Google maintains two separate index. The "main" index, and a "supplementary" index. The "main" index is queried for most queries, the "supplementary" index, however, is included in `site:` queries. Page's (URLs) get relegated to the supplementary index if, for example, they're deemed to be duplicate content.